# multiple option boxes same name jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got multiple select boxes that have the same name. Right now when I select the value from the first select box its submitting that one and updating the database. When I select and item on an other select box its submitting the value from the first one. I feel like the javascript isn't right. Any idea what is wrong?

Heres my html:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
<select class="form-control" name="category[]" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select The Category </option>
    <option value="station">Station</option>
    <option value="equipment">Tools/Equipment</option>
    <option value="supplies">Supplies</option>
</select>
<input id="taskID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" hidden></input>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="category[]"]', function(event){
  $('select[name="category[]"]').each(function(){
          var formData = {
              'task': $('select[name="category[]"]').val(),
              'name': $('input[name="taskID[]"]').val(),
          };
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'php/addressBook.php',
                  data: formData,
                  dataType: 'html',
                  encode: true
              })
              .done(function(msg) {
                  $(".alert").html(msg);
              })  
              .fail(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              })
          event.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

addressBook.php

```
if (isset($_POST['task'])) {

  $task = $_POST['task'];
  $id = $_POST['name'];

  $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE members SET task = ? WHERE id = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $task, $id);
  $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: the `event`parameter has the element included, that triggered that event. Make use of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the class attribute to:  `class="form-control categorySelect"`

```
$('.categorySelect').change(function(event){
      for(selectInstance of $('.categorySelect')){
          var formData = {
          'task': $(selectInstance).val(),
          'name': $(selectInstance).next().val()
          };


          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'php/addressBook.php',
              data: formData,
              dataType: 'html',
              encode: true
          })
          .done(function(msg) {
              $(".alert").html(msg);
          })  
          .fail(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          })
          event.preventDefault();
      }

});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: selectInstance.val is not a function`

Comment: Sorry. What do you get if you try this:     for(selectInstance of $('select[name="category[]"]').val()){
          var formData = {
          'task': selectInstance,
          'name': $('input[name="taskID[]"]').val()
          };

Comment: it appears to be looping through the individual values letters

Comment: I'm not very good myself but I know that it would be much easier to handle if you were to give each `select` element a distinct id or at least another class name. Is there a reason to why you're using the name attribute instead?

Comment: This has to work now. You don't need the id, but add the class selector "categorySelect"

Comment: yeah thats working. good job. how do i go about getting the name `'name': $('input[name="taskID[]"]').val()`

Comment: And I have a small advice regarding your php code, don't forget to add a semicolon at the end of php lines when scattered as fragments in your page, because it gets interpreted as one part and you might get problems :)

Comment: About the name: I thought you only have one input that you didn't include in your code above. Do you have many aswell?

Comment: yeah i have a hidden input passing the id to update the right row. can it be done using `selectInstance of`. I've updated the question. should have posted that initially. my bad.

Comment: I've updated the answer again. Don't forget to mark it as the answer to your question, I need muh points :D

Comment: And remove the id from the input because it has to be special for each one, using many elements with the same Id might lead to errors.